# Configure Same offset for Kafka consumers from different groups

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have ServiceA which produces DomainChangeEvents and commits them into topic in kafka, then ServiceB consumes this events from kafka topic and applies changes to a read model stored in memory. Some of DomainChangeEvent's are reset events and those reset domain to starting point. On restart of ServiceB i want to read ChangeEvents from last reset and re-build domain afterwards.

ServiceB is lunched in docker as replicated service.

As i want all ChangeEvents in each replica of ServiceB i cannot give them same group.id or messages will be loadbalanced and i won't get all events in all replicas. How can i configure ServiceB to continue from latest reset event after restart?

I tried setting random group.id on ServiceB and committing reset message after i consume it but after restart i have different group.id so all messages are consumed from the start again.

Thought about giving different configuration to docker replicas but as i read docker service is configured to be identical in all replicas and thats not an option.

Comment: Do you need to keep all DomainchangeEvents, i.e. those prior to the last reset event?
To me it sounds like instead of reset events you really want to clear your topic and start anew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be storing those points you want your different consumers to start from, by manually committing the offset to, for example, a database.

A table that would look like:

```
Topic  Partition  Offset

topicA 0          112
topicA 1          125
topicB 0          2313
topicB 1          2984
topicB 2          2554
```

Those would be your "latest reset" points, or positions your consumers want to start from. The problem with the `subscribe()` method , as you correctly said, is that it depends on the **group.id** parameter, and plays the consumer rebalancing and coordination game.

In order to consume from a fixed point (or set of points in different partitions), you should make a call to `assign()` instead. With this method, you'll be able to **manually specify a list of partitions to your consumers**. No group.id, no dynamic partition assignment nor offset loading, which is what you seem to need.

After assigning the partitions, you should make a call to `seek()`. With seek, you are telling the consumer from which offset you want to start reading from the partition that was specified on the `assign()` method.

For example, to start reading from the "latest resets" from any topic, you should do something like:

```
//seeking the last offset of topicA's partition0
public void setStartPosition(TopicPartition partition, long offset) 
{
     consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(partition)); //f.e-> partition0
     consumer.seek(partition, offset);                      //f.e -> 112
}
```

Calling this method will position your consumer exactly in the desired position in each partition. I'm not really sure if I'm answering your issue, but hope it helps!

Comment: You can also start reading from Kafka's `__consumer_offsets` topic, which persists the committed offsets. This effectively replaces the database in this design.